# URL path for wordpress categories

Tags: categories

If I have a file called category-sound.php which corresponds to a category in a taxonomy called campaigns for a custom post type called awareness campaigns. what is the url path for this page?

website.com/sound ?

website.com/campaign/sound ?

Comment: It depends on how you registered the taxonomy, in particular on 'rewrite' and 'with_front' arguments and which is your permalink structure. Put somewhere `echo get_term_link( 'sound', 'campaigns' );` and look at the output.

Answer (score 1):

`echo get_term_link( 'sound', 'campaigns' );` gave me the exact path that I need.